# Cantor's diagonal argument - Reference

Tags: real-analysis

My real analysis book uses the Cantor's diagonal argument to prove that the reals are not countable, however the book does not explain the argument.

I would like to understand the Cantor's diagonal argument deeper and applied to other proofs, does anyone have a good reference for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In general, this is a technique called a *diagonal argument*, which involves some sort of self-reference to show a contradiction. If you want to learn more about Cantor's proof, there are two common variants. $(1)$: A construction which shows that you can always find a real number not in a countable list of reals in some $n$-ary expansion, and $(2)$: a general argument that assumes a surjection $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$, and derives a contradiction.

Comment: One of the most instructive things I can think of is to look at (informed) replies to criticisms of the diagonal argument. For instance, see [Refuting the Anti-Cantor Cranks](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527248/13130) and the *Linked* and *Related* questions listed to the right side when you get there. Also, the *Related* questions listed to the right side of your question.

Comment: You'd better say what your book is, because otherwise, you risk to get recommendations for the same book, from those who understood it.